# Variable as table name in node.js mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I use node.js and mysql module.When I execute the following code I want the `table_name` to be set to a variable, not a static table name. For example I want table_name to be todays date.

```
   connection.query(
    "CREATE TABLE `<table_name>` (" +
    "   `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,"+
    "   `text` varchar(50),"+
    "   `created` timestamp NULL,"+
    "   PRIMARY KEY (`title`));"
);
```

Is it possible to set table name as a variable in mysql module for node.js?

Best Regards

Comment: What you provide above is just no valid sql, right? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The module has built in methods to handle your case, you need to escape the variables like this:

```
var tableName = 'THETABLE';

connection.query('CREATE TABLE ?? (column_name1 data_type(size), column_name2 data_type(size), column_name3 data_type(size))', [tableName], function (error, results) {
  // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query
  // results will contain the results of the query (if any)
});
```

You can read more about this feature here:

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#escaping-query-identifiers

Comment: Great! Knew about `?` but not about `??`

Comment: Yep, `?` its for values and `??` is for identifiers.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
async function createTable(db_connection,tableName) {
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db_connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
      }
        


      db_connection.query('CREATE TABLE ?? (doc_source_type varchar(255) default null, 
      doc_id varchar(255) default null, company varchar(255) default null)', 
      [tableName], 
      function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
          reject(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Table created successful");
            resolve(results);
        }
      });


    
});

});
}
```

or you can even try different approach

```
async function setTable(db_connection,tableName) {
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db_connection.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
      }
        

          let createTodos =`create table if not exists ??(
                      id int primary key auto_increment,
                      doc_id varchar(255) default null,
                      doc_source_type varchar(255) default null,
                      company varchar(255) default null,
                      customer varchar(255) default null,
                      rubric_version varchar(255) default null,
                      assessment_type varchar(255) default null,
                      indexed_at datetime default null,
                      assessment_date datetime default null,
                      industry_type varchar(255) default null
                  )`;
                  
     //console.log(createTodos);

      db_connection.query(createTodos, [tableName], function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
          reject(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Table created successful");
            resolve(results);
        }
      });
    
});

});
}
```

Comment: Code only dumps are discouraged on SO. Please edit to highlight important bits of your solutions, and explain how/why they solve the OP's issue.